# Connect submenu to sql and pagination in php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make my dynamic site in php by learning from tutorials and google search. I am stuck in one place.

I want sub-menu from the database i.e SQL. so when user add category in category section in sql then sub should come from the entered categories but it appears empty . Here is the code

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a>
<ul class="submenu pop">
<?php
$result = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT CategoryId,CategoryName FROM category ORDER BY CategoryId ASC");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
?>
<li><a href='#'><?php echo $row['CategoryName'];?></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="construction.php">Directors</a></li>
<li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also please tell me any easiest way for pagination.

Comment: what is the problem  ?

Comment: I can't see any question here. Do you have some?

Comment: There are a ton [of](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination) [pagination](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html) [tutorials](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm) [online](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/).

Comment: The problem is the submenu is connected to sql but its not showing in menu. The submenu appears empty

Comment: you should first check query result..

Comment: The query is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try your code like this :-

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a>
<ul class="submenu pop">
<?php
$result = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT CategoryId,CategoryName FROM category ORDER BY    CategoryId ASC");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
<!-- check edit in line Below -->
<li><a href='<?php echo trim($row['CategoryName']).'php'; ?>'><?php echo $row['CategoryName'];?></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="construction.php">Directors</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Rajeev Ranjan its now showing sub menu items. I want to link to that page also dynamically. What should i do

Comment: @user2055788 tell me the example of your dynamic link

Comment: Like Here is now showing the category in sub menu. I want it to be link to that category page. i.e in the above code where we have entered code for printing CategoryName that should link to the page. I have entered one category in sql i.e canvas and that should link to canvas.php when i ll enter tent that should link to tents.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have the open and close curly brace in your while loop `{ }`

For available plugin refer to this `http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/`

Comment: why should not be used with while curly braces creates code block ?